# Can I separate the parts of a sentence so far away?

Tags: writing, sentence-patterns

> According to Professor Kong, Bo Xilai’s (the governor of Chongqing, whose wife are convicted of killing the British businessman H. Wood) “Chongqing model”, which was known for its tough measures dealing with “underground mafia” on the political front, “singing red (Communist) songs” on the cultural front, and the promotion of “common prosperity” on the economic front, paved the way for China’s future development. (self-made)

All the three merits of the Chongqing model are to be the stones to pave the way. I do not want to  put which clause behind “pave the way..”., because I have to emphasize the which part of the sentence, making the readers pay much attention to the reason of  Professor Kong for thinking that way.

But I doubt that my sentence will be separated too far away. Is there some better way to reorganize the paragraph?

Comment: As an aside, you should say "so far *apart*". "Far *away*" is a geographical term and means "far away from where you are (or from where someone else is)". When referring to distance between *two items*, it should be "far apart"

Comment: Off topic (writing advice request). Check out our [help].

Answer (score 6):

Is there any reason to have such a long sentence in the first place? It is hard to read and easy to misunderstand. Why not

> The “Chongqing model” of Bo Xilai (the governor of Chongqing, whose wife is convicted of killing the British businessman H. Wood) was known for its tough measures dealing with “underground mafia” on the political front, “singing red (Communist) songs” on the cultural front, and the promotion of “common prosperity” on the economic front. According to Professor Kong, this model paved the way for China’s future development.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, which might result in better retention for your readers, is the following:

> According to Professor Kong, the "Chongqing Model" of Bo Xilai (the governor of Chongqing, whose wife was convicted of killing the British businessman H. Wood) comprised three "tough measures," each of which paved the way for China's future development.  They dealt with the following:
>
> - The "underground Mafia" on the political front
> - The "singing of Red Communist songs" on the cultural front
> - The promotion of "common prosperity" on the economic front

You could also number the three tough measures and incorporate each number into the body of the sentence:

> According to Professor Kong, the "Chongqing Model" of Bo Xilai (the governor of Chongqing, whose wife was convicted of killing the British businessman H. Wood) comprised three "tough measures," each of which paved the way for China's future development.  They dealt with  1) the "underground Mafia" on the political front;  2) the "singing of Red Communist songs" on the cultural front; and 3) the promotion of "common prosperity" on the economic front.

Or,

> According to Professor Kong, the "Chongqing Model" of Bo Xilai (the governor of Chongqing, whose wife was convicted of killing the British businessman H. Wood) comprised three "tough measures," each of which paved the way for China's future development.  They dealt with:
>
> 1. The "underground Mafia" on the political front
> 2. The "singing of Red Communist songs" on the cultural front
> 3. The promotion of "common prosperity" on the economic front.